# review data from different sheets and find the refId in all the sheets and give data in single sheet

Tags: excel, vba

in excel there are reference ids in the different sheets find all reference ids and paste the whole row to a new sheet if there is a duplicate reference id paste it in the same row with the headings

i was trying from past 5 days regarding this i have used google and all the other platforms but i can't able to rectify

```
Sub CopyDataWithHeadingsAndAppend()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newWs As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim refId As String
    Dim existingRow As Long
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Create a new worksheet for the copied data
    Set newWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    newWs.Name = "Copied Data"
    
    ' Loop through each worksheet in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ' Skip the new worksheet and any sheet names starting with "Copied_"
        If ws.Name <> "Copied Data" And Left(ws.Name, 7) <> "Copied_" Then
            ' Find the last row in the current worksheet
            lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            
            ' Loop through each row in the current worksheet
            For i = 1 To lastRow
                ' Get the reference id from the current row
                refId = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
                found = False
                
                ' Loop through the new worksheet to check if the reference ID exists
                For existingRow = 1 To newWs.Cells(newWs.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                    If newWs.Cells(existingRow, 1).Value = refId Then
                        found = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next existingRow
                
                If found Then
                    ' If the reference ID is found, append the data to the existing row in the new worksheet
                    For j = 1 To ws.Cells(i, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                        newWs.Cells(existingRow, newWs.Cells(existingRow, newWs.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1).Value = ws.Cells(i, j).Value
                    Next j
                Else
                    ' If the reference ID is not found, copy the entire row to a new row
                    newWs.Cells(newWs.Cells(newWs.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).Value = refId
                    For j = 1 To ws.Cells(i, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                        newWs.Cells(newWs.Cells(newWs.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, newWs.Cells(existingRow, newWs.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1).Value = ws.Cells(i, j).Value
                    Next j
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

[Inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RUXi.jpg)[Inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMHER.jpg)[inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh9U4.jpg) [inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6spt.jpg)

[output after executing the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcNmC.jpg)
[output after executing code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqDFn.jpg)

[Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW9cc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, I made some changes in your code;

1. Added a variable j to the declaration list.
2. Changed the logic where the reference ID is found.
3. Calculate the last column of the target row in the "Copied Data" sheet once.

   Sub CopyDataAndAppend()

   ```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newWs As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastRowNew As Long
    Dim refId As String
    Dim existingRow As Long
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long

    ' Create a new worksheet for the copied data
    Set newWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    newWs.Name = "Copied Data"

    ' Loop through each worksheet in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ' Skip the new worksheet and any sheet names starting with "Copied_"
        If ws.Name <> "Copied Data" And Left(ws.Name, 7) <> "Copied_" Then

            ' Find the last row in the current worksheet
            lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            ' Loop through each row in the current worksheet
            For i = 1 To lastRow
                refId = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
                found = False

                ' Find if the reference ID already exists in the new worksheet
                lastRowNew = newWs.Cells(newWs.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                For j = 1 To lastRowNew
                    If newWs.Cells(j, 1).Value = refId Then
                        existingRow = j
                        found = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j

                ' If reference ID exists, append data, else copy entire row
                If found Then
                    lastColumn = ws.Cells(i, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    ws.Cells(i, 2).Resize(, lastColumn - 1).Copy Destination:=newWs.Cells(existingRow, lastColumn + 1)
                Else
                    ws.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=newWs.Rows(lastRowNew + 1)
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next ws
   ```

   End Sub

Comment: i have executed this logic but it didn't work by the way thanks for your time